# Log out from Drupal 8 with rest

Tags: php, rest, vue.js, drupal-8, logout

From this [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services) looks like logout can be performed sending a post to

```
http://domain/user/logout?_format=json&token=logout_token
```

where *logout_token* is the value returned from a previous login (example below)

```
{
"current_user": {
    "uid": "65",
    "name": "FooBar"
},
"csrf_token": "WDwkGWulI1qBkwDuHtZX8Hakl4X2T7kKIm5kG5StWng",
"logout_token": "l_6TO3cYldLtOx870LI0cYNUwi0wPNSneUA4eZXcZQk"
}
```

Straightforward, but I'm stuck with a 403 error.

I set my **rest User resource** as the following:

```
/user/{user}: GET, PATCH, DELETE
/entity/user: POST  
methods: GET, POST
formats: json
authentication: basic_auth
```

My Drupal **services.yml** contains:

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['*']

    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['*']

    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']

    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false

    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false

    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

Even though Drupal and the caller are on two different servers (be and fe are hosted on two physical different servers), there are no issues with the cors.

I tried two simple scripts (php and vue js - they do the same thing) and getting the same result

**PHP**

```
$url = 'domain/user/logout?_format=json&token=' . $token;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
    ));

$output = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

$response = [
    'info' => $info,
    'data' => json_decode($output, true)
];

curl_close($curl);

return $response;
```

**Vue JS**

```
import Axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$http = Axios

var URL = 'domain/user/logout?_format=json&token=' + this.logout_token

this.$http.post(URL).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
.finally(() => {
    this.loading = false
})
```

I tried to fire the post request from postman and it worked but I noticed it creates a cookie.

Anyone solved/understood how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `logout_token` as the `token` Query string param. Do not confuse that token with the `X-CSRF-Token` that is usually applied to the Headers.

The message you're seeing that mentions 'csrf_token' is either a typo or just the default Parent Class's message and the core developers haven't gotten around to adjusting that REST Logout messaging yet.

Comment: The error is misleading, I'm passing the logout_token anyway

Answer (score 1):

I struggled mightily with log out. CORS was set correctly and the

```
endpoints: http://domain/user/logout?_format=json&token=logout_token
```

was set as mentioned above. The only thing I was missing is this one line:

```
withCredentials: true
```

which then got it working. We can now log in and out! I hope this is helpful to anyone else who is having issues with logout in a decoupled system.

Comment: Where did you set this? In my php script I set ''Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' inside the header (example above) but no luck. Didn't work in my vue script as well

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me because we were using simple oAuth for Authentication.

2 things you should be doing:

1. It should be a Get request and not a Post request.
2. If you are using Simple OAuth for user authentication you won't need the logout token. Use the access token generated by Simple oAuth as an Authorization header.

Here is an example code:-

```
const drupalLogout = async () => {
  const oauthToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('drupal-oauth-token'));
  const logoutoken = oauthToken.access_token;
  if (logoutoken) {
    const res = await fetch(`${base_url}/user/logout?_format=json`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${logoutoken}`,
      },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

I am using the access token stored in my browser localStorage when the user logs in.

Comment: Didn't try with OAuth - from Drupal 'documentation' they say to use a post, I also tried with get but didn't work with neither

Comment: You still need to pass csrf token and yes @MarioCatena - this needs to be a `GET` request not `POST`.